# Сборка мусора в стеке

Tags: c#, стек, сборщик-мусора

Подскажите, пожалуйста, есть ли у значащих типов деструкторы, и происходит ли вызов деструктора при удалении объекта из стека?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Если имеется ввиду финализатор, то нет, структуры не могут иметь финализаторов.
Документация: [Finalizers (C# Programming Guide)](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/classes-and-structs/destructors)

> Finalizers cannot be defined in structs. They are only used with
>   classes.